# Devise invitable not setting invitation token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I invite users by calling:

```
User.invite!(email: email)
```

and have been running into issues where people cannot accept their invitations.  I took a look at the database and noticed several users never had an `:invitation_token` set, even though they were invited.

How might this happen?

Comment: When a user accepts an invitation, the `invitation_token` is set tu `nil` https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/8d15e5e9fc7fa555ec18b342c32bfbbe8172b429/lib/devise_invitable/models.rb#L88 what value does `invitation_accepted_at` have?

Comment: What do you have in server logs on calling `User.invite!(email: email)`? What if you call it from console?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#raw_invitation_token` method. More info [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/scambra/devise_invitable/Devise%2FModels%2FInvitable:raw_invitation_token)